# access 2007 vba recordset.EOF loop returning back first record of set

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, eof, recordset

So I am trying to select some data from a table and then loop through the results and insert new records with modified/additional data into the table. the problem I am having is that when i loop through my recordset It seems to go through the whole set and then back to the first set before exiting.

An example is that I have two records in the table and when I make the selection it should insert only two records but for some reason it inserts 3, the first one repeating twice

Here is my code.

```
Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
Dim query1 As String
query1 = "select [Test Script] from TEST_SCRIPTS where TEST_ID= " & Me.TEST_ID & " "

Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(query1)

If Not (rs1.EOF And rs1.BOF) Then

    rs1.MoveFirst
    Do Until rs1.EOF = True

         INSERT_INTO_TEST_SCRIPTS = "insert into TEST_SCRIPTS ([Test Script], TEST_ID) values (""" & rs1![Test Script] & """, " & Me.TEST_ID & ") "

            DoCmd.SetWarnings False
                DoCmd.RunSQL INSERT_INTO_TEST_SCRIPTS
            DoCmd.SetWarnings True

        rs1.MoveNext

    Loop
End If

rs1.Close
Set rs1 = Nothing
```

I am new to working with recordsets and this one has been bothering me, I appreciate any help.

thanks

Comment: Are you 100% sure the data isn't in there twice in your select?

Comment: Yes, I have even deleted all records and compacted the db..i feel like I am going crazy because this should work i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code should work too, the way it is.

Try setting the recordset to forward only, maybe that will help

> Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(query1, dbOpenForwardOnly)

That being besides the point, it would be more efficient to do an insert select.

> Insert into YourTable (col1, col2) (Select col1, col2 From otherTable)

Comment: I had to remove rs1.MoveFirst because of run time error, but after that everything worked. I appreciate your advise o how to make the query more efficient, Thanks Elias!

Comment: I forgot you wouldn't be able to use that! No problem. For future reference, here are the different recordset definitions-  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa141422(v=office.10).aspx Under Specifying Cursor Types